# Why Linux driver need to compile?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I have a question that is why Linux driver need to compile with Linux source if a new hardware in the unsupported list of Linux kernel? but Windows driver just only need to double click setup.exe, don't need to compile...

Is it the kernel type different? microkernel vs monolithic kernel? or any other reason? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mainly to do with Linux' Monolithic Kernel. This in contrast to Windows' kernel which does not include drivers and drivers are written using the Windows Driver Model which is plug-and-play. Read about the differences in their respective Driver Architectures [here](https://xmodulo.com/linux-vs-windows-device-driver-model.html).

I would suggest you give this article on [Loadable Kernel Modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadable_kernel_module) a read.

Comment: It's a great help for me, thanks Dhruvan.